# Accessing WCF Service with windows authentication from another domain using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, authentication

I have a WCF Service with windows authentication in domain A.

I have a ASP page with jQuery in domain B.

I would like to access the WCF service with Windows Authentication in domain A from domain B.

If domain A has Anonymous Authentication, then the request from domain B works.

If not, I get a "Access is denied" error.

I see two approaches here:

1. Use `webHttpBinding` and implement a `IDispatchMessageInspector`
2. Use JSONP with a callback

Which approach is better?

I already have a basicHttpBinding which is used by other ASP.NET web applications.

Can I extend the basicHttpBinding to support jquery calls?

Answer (score 0):

So you want a workaround/hack to walk around/circumvent Windows security? If so, that's fine. And you have 2 solutions.

1. Setup a gateway service translate requests outside domain A into requests from domain A. If you have biztalk, things will be even easier.
2. Provide a new endpoint with a binding (http or json) not rely on Windows domain security, say username/password and certificate etc. This can be done through configuration alone. So basically clients in domain A may keep using endpoint 1 with Windows security, while clients on the other domains and the Internet will be using endpoint 2 and 3 .

So far I don't see any reason from your post why you need callback.

After all, you should also consult with your system administrators about the details settings

Comment: I think I might use the second option you mentioned with basic authentication. Let me try that and get back here.